# Numpy doesn't provide an attribute

Tags: python, statsmodels, kaggle

I've tried to import a model on Kaggle:
`from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA`
but it returned this error:
`AttributeError: module 'numpy.linalg.lapack_lite' has no attribute '_ilp64'`

There's numpy version 1.18.5. Could you please tell how to fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

I've just back up statmodels library to the version 0.11.0:
`pip uninstall statsmodels -y`
`pip install statsmodels==0.11.0`
It seems like default version 0.11.1 has a bug